# Can I have chrome just update a certain other tab when I click on a link?

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, browser, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

I'd like to have 2 tabs/windows opened and click links on the left one (without it changing) while the right one sort of keeps updating itself by opening the links I click on.

Is that somehow possible? Doesn't have to be chrome.

Comment: Is his for a website you write or in general?  (I suspect the general case is not possible). Are you aware that in most browsers you can right cluck and open a link in a new tab or Window?

Comment: Superlate reply but I'm still interested! Let me put it this way: I often find myself using websites with lots of links that I need to open - but often just for a quick look. When you're dealing with large quantities it can become quite tedious and messy to manage (switching/closing) the opened tabs. Best solution rn seems to be to control-click links, review them, and then close them in bulk. Though it would still be way easier if you had only 2 windows/tabs opened side-by-side at any time, one (unchanging) tab to click links on, the other one displaying the links. Is that somehow possible?